# CSS Transition for left and top not working while font-size transition does

Tags: html, css

I'm creating a text input with a label that starts in the middle of the input and transitions up and left when the input is focused.  For some reason it just pops up in the location I want to move it to instead of transitioning while the size of the font transitions as expected.

My html looks like this

```
<article class="srcryBox inputContainer">
  <input type="text" [attr.id]="InputID" class="srcryBox textInput" placeholder=" " />
  <label [attr.for]="InputID" class="inputLabel">{{LabelText}}</label>
</article>
```

My css looks like this

```
.inputContainer{
  --baseSize-w: var(--large-2-4);
  height: fit-content;
  display: grid;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.textInput{
  grid-area: 1/1/2/2;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: var(--text-article-2);
  --baseSize-h: var(--text-article-2);
  padding: var(--micro-2-1);
  --squishGrowth-h-start: 600px;
  --squishGrowth-h-speed: 2;
  --squishGrowth-h-max: var(--xTiny-2-4);
  border-radius: var(--micro-1-1);
  outline: none;
  border: solid var(--line-light);
}

.textInput:hover{
  border-color: rgb(0, 213, 0);
}

.inputLabel{
  grid-area: 1/1/2/2;
  font-size: var(--text-article-2);
  pointer-events: none;
  place-self: center;
  position: relative;
  transition:
    font-size 200ms ease-in,
    top 200ms ease-in,
    left 200ms ease-in;
}

.textInput:focus ~ .inputLabel,
.textInput:not(:placeholder-shown).textInput:not(:focus) ~ .inputLabel{
  top: -70%;
  left: -40%;
  font-size: var(--text-widget-1);
  padding: 0 var(--micro-1-1);
}
```

Here's a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-c6nktx?file=src%2Fcomponents%2Ftext-input%2Ftext-input.component.css) where you can play with it.  Does anybody know why this is happening and how to fix it?

Comment: For transitions to work, there have to be two different states of the transitioning property. You only have one rule that specifies top and left for .inputLabel, so in effect its trying to transition between "-70%" and "undefined" (for top). Adding default values for top and left on .inputLabel fixes it.  (Even just "top:0; left:0" on .inputLabel should work)

Answer (score 0):

@Optiq has given the answer in a comment.

Here it is as an answer.

For the top and left to show their transitions they have to have start and end values, so the system knows what it is transitioning from and to.

In your code they do not have start values.

The label is correctly positioned however, so all you need to do is to say their positioning is 0 from its 'normal' position.

Add this to .inputLabel

```
top: 0;
left: 0;
```